# In OWL, is possible that a property is the inverse of more than one property?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

it is possible that a property has multiple 'inverseOf' characteristic simultaneously?  For instance:

```
<prop1, owl:inverseOf, prop2>
<prop1, owl:inverseOf, prop3>
<prop1, owl:inverseOf, prop4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with asserting that a property p is the inverseOf more than one property, e.g., q, and r.  It does mean, however, q and r end up being equivalent.  Since

> p inverseOf q
>   p inverseOf r

means that

> p(x,y) implies q(y,x)
>   p(x,y) implies r(y,x)
>   q(y,x) implies p(x,y)
>   r(y,x) implies p(x,y)

we can infer that

> q(y,x) implies r(y,x)
>   r(y,x) implies q(y,x)

which means that

> q equivalentProperty r

Comment: I'm sure you mean `p(x,y) implies q(y,x)`? Otherwise, you could infer that `p inverseOf p` by simply using the chain `p(x,y) implies q(x,y), q(x,y) implies p(x,y) => p(x,y) implies p(x,y)`. But I'm sure you did this by mistake :D

Comment: @AKSW Oops!  Good catch!  Fixed now.